# MSSQL enterprise cluster - track of failovers

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, database, cluster

In an MSSQL Enterprise cluster where can I find a log of past fail over events (when they happened and which instances were re-assigned?)

Answer (score 1):

The following image might help you:

[image: Windows Failover Cluster Event Log]

I expect exporting this Event Log from each cluster member and then combining the exported values (Perhaps using Excel) will show you what you want to know.

Answer (score 1):

Powershell's Get-EventLog to the rescue....

Cluster failovers write to the event logs of the servers.  You can use Powershell to query the event logs for the specific events you want to retrieve.